# Recursion Control flow

Tags: c, recursion, kernighan-and-ritchie

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printd(int n)
{
    if(n/10)
        printd(n/10);
    putchar(n%10+'0');
}
```

In the above code consider n as a positive integer 
and its value be 123.

First time,123 is passed to printd (first printd)
Second time,12 is passed to printd (second printd)
Third time,1 is passed to printd (third printd) and putchar prints 1

Then after the control flows to second printd,what is the value of n?
Since it is an automatic variable it's value of 1 in third printd vanishes once the function ends and gets the value of 12 in second printd.

If so,second printd will again lead to third printd and so....

But the program beautifully prints 123.

Where did my understanding on control flow and values for variables during function invocation went wrong?

FYI,the program is from K&R section 4.10 recursion

Comment: In second `printd`, `n` is 12. "_If so,second printd will again lead to third printd_" No. second `printd` starts from where it stopped, and not from the start.

Comment: @Cool Guy,If I'm right,the second printd ends by putchar(n%10+'0') where n=12.??

Comment: Consider not wasting a lot of time in understanding recursion, as it has _very_ limited uses. (It can be used in a few rare implementations of binary tree algorithms and that's about the only case where it makes sense.) All beginners learning c spend far too much time on understanding special features like recursion, while they should focus on learning proper program design and avoiding language pitfalls instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong here:

> If so,second printd will again lead to third printd

second `printd` starts from where it stopped, and not from the start of the function `printd`. So, the `putchar` is executed in second `printd` which prints 2 and the same thing happens in the first `printd`, printing 3.

Comment: Thanks man.I got it.The second printd is like an expansion with the first one and so on....